# why can't I print the copied string individually?

Tags: c++, c++14

```
string s="1 23";
string a;
a[0]=s[2];a[1]=s[3];
cout<<a;
```

Here, I can't get output string a. But I can get all the individual elements by a[0].

Comment: Consider that `string a;` creates a string of 0 characters.  An "empty string".  What is your code attempting to do with those 0 characters?

Answer (score 7):

Because `a` is empty, `a[i]` accesses it out of bounds for every possible `i`, causing undefined behavior.

Use `a.push_back(s[i])` to add characters to `a`.

Comment: Or, `a += s[i]`

Answer (score 2):

`a` is initialized as an empty string, so no memory is allocated for its characters, so when accessing it with `[]`, you access unallocated memory, and that's undefined behavior.

One way to solve it is to create `a` as string with enough characters allocated. You can use the `std::string` fill constructor, that fills the string with a char of your choice:

```
std::string s = "1 23";
std::string a(s.size(), ' ');
```

This way you can put the characters in any index that exists in `s`.